# Trinomial extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let F be the smallest field containing the rationals, such that whenever a and b are in F, and d>e are positive integers, the polynomial $x^d + ax^e + b$ splits in f.

How do you prove that F is not algebraically closed, and find a specific algebraic number not in F?

-- Joe Shipman

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: I came up with it by generalizing the "ultraradical" symbol in order to express solutions of higher degree polynomials explicitly. Anything expressinle via radicals and generalized ultraradicals still comes from a sequence of trinomial extensions.